# add another column as second X axis label in Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have a 15minutes interval time series for several camera. each camera can collect 3 types of movement in four different leg. There is a `control_factor` that was present for an hour for each camera. I want to show the total of counts in each leg for each camera (each camera in separate plots ) for every 15minutes. and in the x axis, which is the time, next to each time, or under, I want to write yes, if the factor is true and no if the factor is false.

You can create the data using the following lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to create date range with 15-minute intervals
def create_date_range(start_date, end_date, interval):
    date_range = []
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        date_range.append(current_date)
        current_date += interval
    return date_range

# Function to create DataFrame
def create_dataframe(start_date, end_date, interval):
    date_range = create_date_range(start_date, end_date, interval)

    data = []
    for date_time in date_range:
        for camera in range(1, 5):
            for leg in range(1, 5):
                for movement in range(1, 4):
                    count = 1  # You can set count based on your requirements
                    control_factor = True if date_time.hour == 14 and camera == 1 else False
                    data.append([date_time, f'Cam{camera}', f'Leg{leg}', f'Move{movement}', count, control_factor])

    columns = ['DateTime', 'Camera', 'Leg', 'Movement', 'Count', 'control_factor']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    return df

# Set start and end dates
start_date = datetime(2024, 1, 27, 14, 0, 0)
end_date = datetime(2024, 1, 27, 16, 0, 0)

# Set time interval
interval = timedelta(minutes=15)

# Create DataFrame
df = create_dataframe(start_date, end_date, interval)

# Display DataFrame
print(df)
```

I tried the plot:

```
# List of unique cameras in your data
unique_cameras = df['Camera'].unique()

# Iterate over each camera
for camera in unique_cameras:
    # Filter data for the current camera
    df_camera = df[df['Camera'] == camera]

    # Group by DateTime, Leg, and Movement, summing the counts and taking the first control_factor value
    grouped_df = df_camera.groupby(['DateTime', 'Leg', 'Movement'])[['Count', 'control_factor']].agg({'Count': 'sum', 'control_factor': 'first'}).reset_index()

    # Plot the data
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
    ax = sns.barplot(x='DateTime', y='Count', hue='Leg', data=grouped_df, ci=None)

    # Rotate x-axis labels for better visibility
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')

    plt.title(f'Sum of Counts for Each Leg Over Time ({camera})')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Sum of Counts')

    # Annotate bars with control_factor values
    for index, row in grouped_df.iterrows():
        plt.text(index, row['Count'], str(row['control_factor']), ha='center', va='bottom')

    plt.show()
```

it shows true or false over each bar, but I want it under the x axis along with the time. I also want to make the colours like lighter for those bars with control-factor = False. Just same colour as the other bars, but a bit lighter.

Here is what I am trying to do!

[image]

I am open to use other library as well.

Answer (score 1):

You get weird-looking graphs that extend to infinity on the x-axis because of this line of code, where you are looping through each row item, which is not necessary :

```
    # # Annotate bars with control_factor values
for index, row in grouped_df.iterrows():
plt.text(index, row['Count'], str(row['control_factor']), ha='center', va='bottom')
```

1. To change color see the `palette` argument in seaborn [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

I'm using  `palette = 'muted'` in the plot below

2. To change the x-axis labels to control-factors update your `set_xticklabels` line. I'm using the first control factor for each date, but you might have to change that if you expect duplicates

```
labs = grouped_df.groupby('DateTime').agg({'control_factor':'first'})['control_factor'].to_list()
ax.set_xticklabels(labs, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to keep both time and `control_factor` together as label and want to only change the color for those with false

Comment: Can you add an image in your question, of what your expected output is exactly? I'm not sure what your end goal is rn